# soap:address location from http to https

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I have a few web-services, such as:

```
<wsdl:port name="CalcWithPerson22HttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:CalcWithPerson22Soap11Binding">  
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/CalcWithPerson22"/>  
  </wsdl:port>
```

In these I need to change the  `soap:address location` from "http" to "https".

Where in the WSDL files do I need to make the change?

Comment: I am few webservice, suppose as below.


<wsdl:port name="CalcWithPerson22HttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:CalcWithPerson22Soap11Binding">  
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/CalcWithPerson22"/>  
        </wsdl:port> 

In these i need to change the  soap:address location from "http" to "https".

Where exactly i need to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "https" here inside xml file

```
<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SimpleHTTPServer"> <parameter name="port">8443</parameter> </transportReceiver>
```

Answer (score 3):

1.5.3 maint release already had a support for https. So we can use that as well

November 12, 2010 - Apache Axis2/Java Version 1.5.3 Released!
1.5.3 is a maintenance release that contains the following improvements:

- Improved support for SSL when using the servlet transport: Axis2 can now be configured so that generated WSDLs contain https endpoints (AXIS2-4465).
- Improved compatibility with Rampart (AXIS2-3213 and AXIS2-4870) and Sandesha2 (potential HTTP connection pool starvation).
- Axiom has been upgraded to 1.2.10. This version contains performance improvements relevant for Rampart.
- Application (business) faults are no longer logged at level ERROR (AXIS2-4280).
- Improved conformance to the SAAJ specifications. The 1.5.3 release contains a set of fixes and improvements for the SAAJ implementation developed on the trunk and not included in previous releases from the 1.5 branch.
- Axis2 now relies exclusively on dependencies available from the Maven central repository, and no other Maven repositories are required. This in particular fixes a build problem that appeared after the 1.5.2 release.
- The Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA plugins are again available for download via the Axis2 Web site (previous 1.5.x versions could only be downloaded from the Maven repository).

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all you have to make sure the application server where you are deploying these services need to be running on SSL/https.

2) There is no need to change the wsdl. Just change the endpoint in the client from where you intend to invoke these services to https.

However, still you have a requirement to change the soap address in wsdl. Just make this change :

```
<soap:address location="https://localhost:8080/axis2/services/CalcWithPerson22"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

**axis2.xml** Check for *https transportReceiver*. Its enabled by default in axis2 versions above 1.5.3.

```
<transportReceiver name="https"
class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SimpleHTTPServer">
<parameter name="port">8443</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

**service.xml** If you want to run your service on https only, it will looks like this

```
<service name="TestWebservice" >
    <description>
        Please Type your service description here
    </description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only"
class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
        <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out" 
class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <transports> 
        <transport>https</transport> 
    </transports>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass">xx.xxx.xxx.TestWebservice</parameter>
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks.. yes my application server runs on https. Client is asking to change the soap address from http to https. <wsdl:port name="RTAPDevServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:RTAPDevServiceSoap11Binding"><soap:address location="http://fo:8443/app/services/RTAPDevService.RTAPDevServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/"/></wsdl:port>. I want to know how can i change from http to https and where i need to change. Can you please tell be the exact location, and how is this soap address getting generated.

Comment: When you generate the wsdl, it will take http://ip:port/service by default. You need to manually edit your wsdl. Open your wsdl in any editor, change <soap:address location="https://ip:8443/service"/>

Comment: u mean 2 say there is no way that whenever we acess the wsdl from browser with the url, we cannot get "https", Actuall the issue is this only, client is asking that whenever he want 2 see the wsdl through broswer the soap address should come as https

Comment: Ok, if you will be running your service on https only. If you are using Axis2 1.5.3 and above, change <transports>
     <transport>https</transport>
</transports> in service.xml. Then generate the service.

Comment: i already added this in axis2.xml...    <transportReceiver name="https"
                       class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SimpleHTTPServer">
        <parameter name="port">8443</parameter>
    </transportReceiver>

Comment: I added the  <transports> 
        <transport>HTTP</transport>
    </transports> after the </description> closed tag, but my then i cannot see my service at all, what could be the reason.

Comment: it gives me exception org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: Service [ RTAPDevService] is trying to expose in a transport : <transports> 
        <transport>HTTPS</transport>
    </transports> and which is not available in Axis2

Comment: Check my answer on your other thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063300/change-soapaddress-location-from-http-to-https/10072185#10072185