# change soap:address location from http to https

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

yes my application server runs on https. Client is asking to change the soap address from http to https.

client is asking that whenever he want 2 see the wsdl through broswer the soap address should come as https

i already added this in axis2.xml...

```
<transportReceiver name="https"      class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SimpleHTTPServer"> <parameter     name="port">8443</parameter> 
</transportReceiver>
```

I added the below in service.xml

```
<transports> <transport>HTTPS</transport> </transports>
```

after the  closed tag, but it give me below error.

it gives me exception

```
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: Service [ RTAPDevService] is trying to expose in a transport : <transports> <transport>HTTPS</transport> </transports> and which is not available in Axis2 –
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in **service.xml**. It should be :

```
<transports><transport>https</transport></transports>
```

not HTTPS.

Your **wsdl** will look like this:

```
 <wsdl:service name="SampleService">
<wsdl:port name="SampleServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:SampleServiceSoap11Binding">
<soap:address location="https://localhost:8443/Axis2HttpsProject/services/SampleService.SampleServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="SampleServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:SampleServiceSoap12Binding">
<soap12:address location="https://localhost:8443/Axis2HttpsProject/services/SampleService.SampleServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="SampleServiceHttpsEndpoint" binding="ns:SampleServiceHttpBinding">
<http:address location="https://localhost:8443/Axis2HttpsProject/services/SampleService.SampleServiceHttpsEndpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

And one thing more,make sure you have added **http-core** jar.

Comment: I have not tested it..was busy looking in one of my SSL issues posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072351/two-way-ssl-authentication)..if you have any idea please give some pointers...whatever you have mentioned i will test it out and will surely post...

Comment: Hello Shashankaholic... i added as suggested by you in service.xml.. but still same error...    (org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: Service [ RTAPDevService] is trying to expose in a transport : <transports><transport>https</transport></transports> and which is not available in Axis2... i have this jar file in my application "httpcore-4.0.jar" and my service.xml is as folows.......................

Comment: <service name="RTAPDevService">
<description>NAF Service</description>
<transports><transport>https</transport></transports>
<parameter name="ServiceClass">com.headstrong.zephyr.csl.endpoint.NAFEndpoint
</parameter></service>

Comment: Which axis2 version are you using? I used axis2 1.6.1 and it generated wsdl as required successfully. I think it was an issue(Axis2-4465) with previous versions, which is resolved in latest.

Comment: All jars releated to axis corresponds to "1.5.1" version..this means i need to upgrade the same...

Comment: Yes, i would suggest you to try with axis2 1.6.1

Comment: There are many jar files in my application folder with axis 1.5.1..do i need to replace all of them or any particular jar file..??

Comment: Hello Shashankaholic... i tried with axis2 1.6.1 jars, but still the same issue...

Comment: @user1231230 Sorry, but i was able to succesfully achieve what you intend using axis2 1.6.1.

Comment: It worked actually...i changed the transportReceiver name="https"  in axis2.xml and after that it worked.. thanks

Comment: Anyways, congrats. This was proving very painful to you ,i guess. And don't forget to accept my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

**Create a certificate**

`keytool -genkey -alias localhost -keypass password -keystore /choose/a/path/localhost.bin -storepass password -keyalg RSA`

**Enabling SSL on server side for AXIS2 in tomcat**

Add the following in `Server.xml` of tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
       maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
       keystoreFile="/choose/a/path/localhost.bin"
       keystorePass="password" keyAlias="localhost"/>
```

**Change axis2.xml**

(You can use both: http and https)

```
<transportReceiver name="http"
               class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
               <parameter name="port">8080</parameter>
           </transportReceiver>
<transportReceiver name="https"
               class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
               <parameter name="port">8443</parameter>
           </transportReceiver>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi enrmarc, i think you have mis understood my problem. Question is in the SOAP address in wsdl, i want it to make it from "HTTP" to "HTTPS", for that i edited in service.xml of webservice and added the above mentioned code, but still it did not work, and i got the exception as mentioned above...

Answer (score 0):

In the standalone.xml i did those changes:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
        <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
        <wsdl-host>jbossws.undefined.host</wsdl-host>
        <wsdl-port>443</wsdl-port>
        <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
```