# How to change <soap:address location=".."/>?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

Basically, I have followed the netbeans guide on creating a web service called HelloWorld.

When I opened the HelloWorld.wsdl file to change the  to  and restarting the web service and from the web browser, navigating to .../SOAPHelloWorld/HelloWorld?wsdl, the changes does not seem to reflect there.

Does anyone have a clear solution for this? Could it be that I'm making changes to the wrong file?

And also, when I run the web service, it automatically access it via http, how can I change it to default to https only?

Comment: I am not sure but you should change your service provider class ie. a java class not the wsdl directly because as far as I could understand you have the automatically generated wsdl. So change java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you describe how deploy or publish this WSDL? What is server name?

> When I opened the HelloWorld.wsdl file to change the to and restarting
>   the web service and from the web browser, navigating to
>   .../SOAPHelloWorld/HelloWorld?wsdl, the changes does not seem to
>   reflect there.

Maybe you are not published this WSDL. If you have project need to build and deployed to server (Tomcat, Glassfish etc.). Please check this link:

https://weblogs.java.net/blog/bhaktimehta/archive/2008/03/developing_webs.html

Comment: The .wsdl file is automatically published when I run the web service.

Comment: Here is link for http --> https topic [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063300/change-soapaddress-location-from-http-to-https/10072185#10072185)

Comment: I haven't tried create SOAP web service by NetBeans demo. I always create WSDL and XSD and therefore generated this WSDL. Could you check your java code, exspecialy webservice annotation? Maybe you are change only WSDL and not change java code.

Comment: In the link that you have provided, their using axis which in the case, I'm not. Trying to change it to run on https is such a headache.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by adding this statement into the web.xml file.
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>profile</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/profile/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

Answer (score 0):

actually,the file "HelloWorld.wsdl" which you edit is just use to show the information.it can not effect anyother things of you project,you should edit by you code.like endpoint.publish("...192.168.0.84:8888/Service/WebService.asmx?wsdl"); see if this help

Comment: Still, does not reflect when I browse the .wsdl file from the web browser